# How to create ical files from HTML table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, icalendar

I'm trying to create importable calender events from a website.
The website has the events clustered into a standard html table.

I was wondering if beautfulsoup is the correct way to takel this problem, because i only get the first entry and then nothing.

```
quote_page = "http://www.ellen-hartmann.de/babybasare.html"

page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", {"border": "1"})

td = table.find("td", text="Veranstaltungstyp&nbsp;")

print table

td_next = table.find_next("tr")

print td_next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're stopping because your using `find()` which gets one matching tag, instead of `find_all()` which gets all the matching tags.  Then you have to loop over the results

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://www.ellen-hartmann.de/babybasare.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# now let's find every row in every table
for row in soup.find_all("tr"):

    # grab the cells within the row
    cells = row.find_all("td")

    # print the value of the cells as a list.  This is the point where
    # you will need to filter the rows to figure out what is an event (and
    # what is not), determine the start date and time, and convert the values 
    # to iCal format.
    print([c.text for c in cells])
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem, why I was getting only one dataset.